# Reviewing with Perforce and Swarm

Tags: perforce, swarm

I am trying to make a review of change shelved with command line client. My friend created new file and added it with p4 add filename. Then it was shelved (p4 shelve). Then, on our Swarm website he found his change and clicked "Request Review" and added me as a reviewer. I can see view the review, comment changes, vote, but I cannot approve, reject, commit changes - the button "Needs Review" is disabled. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible his change is part of a Swarm "project." Only project members can approve changes that touch the project.

You can tell if the change is part of a project by looking at the review heading - there's a line which says "myfriend authored this 2 days ago for ". If  is a project name, you must be a member of that project to approve. If it's just a depot path, then there's probably some other reason.